# Sentry.Serilog not adding BreadCrumbs

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, serilog, sentry

I'm pretty new to Sentry and I'm trying to test the basic features of Serilog / Sentry integration in my Asp.Net Core web application.

I'm using the version 3.21.0 of the SentrySeirlog NuGet package since this is the version of my sentry.io server.

Here is my configuration

```
 Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
                .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                .Enrich.WithMachineName()
                .WriteTo.Async(a => a.Console())
                .WriteTo.Sentry(o =>
                {
                    o.MinimumBreadcrumbLevel = LogEventLevel.Verbose;
                    o.MinimumEventLevel = LogEventLevel.Verbose;
                    o.Dsn = configuration["Sentry:Dsn"];
                    o.AttachStacktrace = bool.Parse(configuration["Sentry:AttachStackTrace"]);
                    o.Environment = configuration["AppSettings:Environment"];
                })
                .CreateLogger();
```

I've read the official documentation and this is supposed to create an Event on my sentry.io instance for any call to Log. from Serilog.

The actual result on my Sentry instance is that it is creating an Event for every call to Log.Error or any unhandled exception in the code, but it is not adding any BreadCrumb to that event.

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing ?

I tried to change the values of these properties with no change in the result.

I also tried to manually add a BreadCrumb using SentrySdk.AddBreadCrum("My BreadCrumb") in a Catch block and this is working as expected. However, I would like to do it through Serilog and not using the SentrySdk class.

Answer (score 1):

Sentry [creates breadcrumbs for SeriLog events ***after*** capturing those events](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-dotnet/blob/65e9ef63530b3c1a8c175480a66f4734f62b0676/src/Sentry.Serilog/SentrySink.cs#L116-L119), so if you have three separate log messages in SeriLog (A, B and C), each captured by Sentry, the first event (A) will be sent without any breadcrumb... but A will also be added as a breadcrumb (breadcrumbA). The next event (B) gets sent with breadcrumbA and the last event (C) gets captured with 2 breadcrumbs: breadcrumbA and breadcrumbB.

That's just what breadcrumbs in Sentry are for:

> Sentry uses breadcrumbs to create a trail of events that happened prior to an issue.

Also note that [Breadcrumbs get stored in the "scope" in Sentry](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-dotnet/blob/65e9ef63530b3c1a8c175480a66f4734f62b0676/src/Sentry/HubExtensions.cs#L148) and each new transaction gets it's own scope... In the context of an ASP.NET Core application, typically you'd get a new transaction for each request to your ASP.NET Core app... so the breadcrumbs will get reset at the start of each request.